# I have been downgraded on Nightjet due to changes in train formations. Am I eligible for compensation?

Tags: trains, compensation, night-transport

While riding Nightjet sleeper trains in the recent months, I encountered situations in which I was downgraded because my type of booked accommodation was not available on the consist that showed up. This happened twice.

Am I eligible for compensation, and how to proceed with this specific type of claim?

**First situation**

Booked a deluxe sleeper with shower on Basel-Hamburg. The train that pulled in that night missed one of the two sleeping cars it normally runs with. We were reassigned to a regular (smaller) compartment instead and the car type running on the route had no shared shower.

I guess the missing car could have had a technical issue and remained in the shop.

Apart from eventual records of the events on that night related to the date and train number, I did not receive any actual receipt that I can use as a proof of downgrade.

**Second situation**

Booked a bunk in a 6-couchette compartment. The car with my assigned number was a seated compartment car instead of couchette. The attendant made its best to make up for it, giving me an empty compartment and the couchette bedding.

I could lie flat but there was no way to block out the light; no curtains to the corridor and the window had a sun shade only, AC was too hot even on the lowest setting and no bottles of water provided... what a night!

The attendant printed a voucher certifying the fact that I was downgraded.

Comment: Did they refund the whole ticket? or just the difference vs. the seat?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When the booked travel class is not available you are indeed entitled to a compensation.

You can contact ÖBB via the form here: [Passenger Rights & Reimbursement](https://www.oebb.at/en/reiseplanung-services/kundenservice/refundierung-chatbot)

Comment: Interesting, this seems to be ÖBB's policy -- but are they doing this by choice, or is this required as per some regulation?

Comment: As far as I know it's based on this EU regulation: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?toc=OJ%3AL%3A2021%3A172%3ATOC&uri=uriserv%3AOJ.L_.2021.172.01.0001.01.ENG

Comment: I was in a similar situation last year and confirmed this via the ÖBB hotline that also pointed me to the web form mentioned above. On the journey in question we additionally arrived with a delay of about 2 hours at our destination. As the web form only allows to input a single reason for the reimbursement I sent 2 requests for the trip and got compensated for both (pretty cheap tickets in the end ...). There was however a delay of several weeks between the confirmation of the 2 refunds.

Comment: @Artemis Is it? I don't see any relevant rules in that regulation.

Comment: Update: after using the form, I received the refund and it took roughly one month to process. You can get a voucher with some bonus added on top, or regular refund on the original payment method.